# Did Chuck Norris participate in Czech T-Mobile adverts?

Tags: advertising

There is [a series of TV adverts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL99D8EA34B6D0AEA2) on Czech mobile service provider T-Mobile. The adverts featured Czech jokes on Chuck Norris and he himself played there. But wasn't it a twin, which would allow the ads to get much cheaper. So, where is the truth, please?

*(I hope the question is on-topic and reasonably well stated. If not, please let me know. It's my first time asking here.)*

Comment: You think T-Mobile can't afford to hire Chuck Norris to do an ad spot?

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not sure whether you know the Czech culture, everybody here saves every koruna. I'm not sure they would invest into it if they didn't have to.

Comment: Okay, but T-Mobile isn't a Czech company. It's an American company. And American companies love to hire celebrities to do their ad spots. And if any company can afford to hire an old, dried up celeb (read: cheap), it's T-Mobile.  And the vids on Youtube sure look and sound like the real Chuck Norris to me.

Comment: There's not any real notable claim in this question...

Comment: There is an implied claim, that the person in the commercials who claims to be Chuck Norris is Chuck Norris.

Comment: @Flimzy: T-Mobile is American? Wait what? Pretty sure the US subsidiary is one of many belonging to a german company.

Comment: @DavidMulder: You're right... it's not an American company (any more)... the T-Mobile I'm most familiar with (T-Mobile USA) was originally a US company, but was bought by Deutsche Telekom in 2001... sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @Flimzy: Yeah, they did buy a US company and used it as their basis for their US subsidiary. The paperwork for a telecom company is far from nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.examiner.com/article/chuck-norris-hired-to-make-czechs-talk-by-t-mobile), and [dozens of others](https://www.google.com/search?q=T-mobile+chuck+norris+ads&oq=T-mobile+chuck+norris+ads&aqs=chrome..69i57.5146j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8#q=T-mobile+chuck+norris+hired) Chuck Norris was indeed hired by T-Mobile to appear in their television advertisements on Czech TV.